# How to display map in MapServer?

Tags: mapserver, ms4w, p-mapper

I haven't found any good explanation yet about how to display a map in MapServer (localhost).

I have MS4W with p.mapper in my PC. I have created a base .map file, shape files and html file.

Please tell me the exact steps in which folder I put these files to be displayed in p.mapper?

Answer (score 1):

MapServer is software for creating services that create maps on request by a client. In other words you can't display a map IN MapServer, you can only get MapServer to provide a map for a some client, such as a JavaScript web based map client built using OpenLayers, or a Desktop client like QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

[How to Generate a Simple Map using Mapserver and a Shapefile.](http://www.gistutor.com/mapserver/3-beginner-mapserver-tutorials/7-how-to-generate-a-simple-map-using-mapserver-and-a-shapefile.html)